# Is the JavaScript API capable of creating Power Query queries?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, powerquery, excel-addins

I'm currently investigating whether it's possible to port a VBA addin I maintain, to a web-based Office addin. The purpose of my existing addin is to create queries which can be refreshed to pull live report data into the worksheet from the web front end of a database application.

In VBA I can do this quite simply with QueryTables:

`Set Query = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=FullURL, Destination:=ActiveCell)`

The [JavaScript API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.query?view=excel-js-preview) mentions the *Excel.Query* class which represents a Power Query query, but the properties and methods seem to be read-only and I see no mention of how to create one of these and add it to the sheet, only examine existing ones.  Is it yet possible to create a new query using Office JS? Alternatively, can I achieve my goals using a different type, like LinkedData or DataConnection?

Comment: Queries are implemented in the JS API. But it doesn't look like they support an Add method. You can see more information on the Query class in the Excel JavaScript API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.query?view=excel-js-preview

Comment: @BrianGonzalez that was the conclusion I drew from the documentation, yes. Given the Query class has no write methods I wondered whether it's possible to create them some other way - tell the sheet to add a query, not the query to add itself to the sheet, that kind of thing - but it's looking like it's just not possible to make queries with the JS API.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that it will be possible to do at some point in the future. But you are correct that it is not possible to do right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no API in Office JavaScript Library to enable creating/writing Power Queries. It may be added someday if there is sufficient demand, but that will be at least a year from now. Please suggest this at [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).

Comment: 1yr is coming up lol, here's hoping